# QGLWidget's paintGL() method called from which Qt thread?

Tags: multithreading, qt, opengl, rendering, qglwidget

suppose I use the QGLWidget's paintGL() method to draw into the widget using OpenGL. After the Qt called the paintGL() method, it automatically triggers a buffer swap. In OpenGL, this buffer swap usually blocks the calling thread until the frame rendering to the background buffer is completed, right? I wonder which Qt thread calls the paintGL as well as the buffer swap. Is it the main Qt UI thread? If it is, wouldn't that mean that the block during the buffer swap also blocks the whole UI? I could not find any information about this process in general..

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use the QGLWidget very often, but consider that yes, if swapBuffers() is synchronous the Qt GUI thread is stuck. This means that during that operation you'll be unable to process events.

Anyway, if you're experiencing difficulties while doing this, consider reading [this article](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qq/qq06-glimpsing.html#writingmultithreadedglapplications) which manage to allow multithreaded OpenGL to overcome this difficulty.

Even better, [this article](http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2011/06/03/threaded-opengl-in-4-8/) explains well the situation and introduces the new multithreading OpenGL capabilities in Qt 4.8, which is now in release candidate.

Comment: Thanks for answer and links :-). The paragraph "Buffer swapping thread" in the second link explains pretty much the ploblem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> In OpenGL, this buffer swap usually blocks the calling thread until the frame rendering to the background buffer is completed, right?

It depends on how it is implemented. Which means that it varies from hardware to hardware and driver to driver.

> If it is, wouldn't that mean that the block during the buffer swap also blocks the whole UI?

Even if it does block, it will only do so for 1/60th of a second. Maybe 1/30th if your game is slowing down. If you're really slow, 1/15th. The at most one keypress or mouse action that the user gives will still be in the message queue.

The issue with blocking isn't about the UI. It will be responsive enough for the user to not notice. But if you have strict timings (such as you might for a game), I would suggest avoiding `paintGL` at all. You should be rendering when you want to, not when Qt tells you to.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :-). Even if the characteristics of the blocking are implementation dependent, at least the blocking must happen at some point, right? Otherwise we would have constantly more request for frames at the CPU side than the GPU can render.

Comment: When speaking about the actual blocking time, I think you referring to the waining time for synchronization with the display? Ins't the difference of the time needed on CPU side with the rendering time itself the worst case blocking time we could? My application target is not a game but more like scientific visualization. I think I will have to render very complex frames with a low frame rate. Assume that it would take 1 second for the GPU to render the frame but only some tens of milliseconds to initiate the frame on CPU side. This would totally kill my main gui thread.

Comment: @DyingSoul: "Even if the characteristics of the blocking are implementation dependent, at least the blocking must happen at some point, right?" No, it doesn't have to happen at all. If the driver is threaded or using a triple-buffer internally, it can just queue your commands and fire them off later.